# Github actions: Add ref to checkout conditonally?

Tags: github-actions

I need a small help in syntax of github actions.

So I am taking one of the optional inputs as:

```
DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH:
 description: branch that needs to be deployed
 type: string
 required: false
```

And I want to use it in one of the checkout options as:

```
 - name: Checkout repo
   uses: actions/checkout@v3
   with:
     ref: ${​​{​​ inputs.DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH }​​}​​
```

Now I want to add ref only if the DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH is passed and ignore otherwise. So I came up with this:

```
- name: Checkout repo
  if: inputs.DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH != ''
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    ref: ${{ inputs.DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH }}
```

Can someone please validate if this is right way to identify undefined `DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH​​​​​​​` or should I use some other variable?

Comment: If it's empty which branch you would like to use?

Comment: If empty I would like to use the branch that checkout uses when no with: is provided

Comment: I think it's ok to pass the ref as is `ref: ${{ inputs.DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH }}`(Without any conditionals) because from the source it seems like it will take care of this [check](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/main/src/input-helper.ts#L59-L72). Anyway I would recommend to test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly pass the input to `actions/checkout@v3` with `${​​{​​inputs.DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH}​​}​​`(without any conditionals).

```
 - name: Checkout repo
   uses: actions/checkout@v3
   with:
     ref: ${​​{​​ inputs.DEPLOYMENT_BRANCH }​​}​​
```

This is because from [the source code](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/main/src/input-helper.ts#L59-L72) the action will fallback to the default if the `ref` input evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Would !github.ref if github.ref is empty string return true? I know its typescript but just want to be 200% sure. And why are you using default: ''? Wouldn't keeping required to false mean that it would automatically be empty string?

Comment: Thank you very much @Abdul Niyas P M for the clarification